# My screen is distorted while installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, live-usb

I can't install Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop.

After I boot the LiveUSB (a bootable from yumi) when I enter Install the screen is distorted and I can't install.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Boot from the USB, and as soon as you see the images in the bottom middle of the screen, perss your <kbd>Shift</kbd>.  Once that is done you will see the image below

[image]

Choose your language, and on the next screen, press <kbd>F6</kbd>, scroll down to nomodeset, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to choose it, and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and choose the first or second option on the menu.  See if that helps.

[image]